# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '< Error While passing List Parameters in GeoServer View

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, javascript, openlayers, jquery

Hello I am creating Geoserver view to view my result and for zoom to result.
My Sql Query is like **`SELECT * FROM geotable WHERE gid IN (%gid%)`**

View Parameters to Query like **`1,2,3`**

Regular Expression like **'^[\w\d\s]+$'**

**My Zoom function like**

```
  function binddata(data) {
        myObject = JSON.parse(data.d);
        gid = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
            gid.push(myObject[i].gid);
        }
        //var plcd = plcd1[0];
        ZoomtoParcelsByAcers(gid, SearchResultsLayer);
}


//Function to escape comma in viewparameters
    String.prototype.replaceAll = function (search, replacement) {
        var target = this;
        return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
    };

    function EscapeCommasSemiColons(input) {
        return input.toString().replaceAll(",", "\\,");
    }


function ZoomtoParcelsByAcers(gid, SearchResultsLayer) {
        $.ajax({

            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/plotgeo/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=plotgeo:vwnew&maxFeatures=5000&outputFormat=text/javascript',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: "parseResponse",
            data: {

                viewparams: "gid:" + EscapeCommasSemiColons(gid)
            },

            success: function (response) {

                search(response);
            }
        });

 }
```

**When i pass multiple parameters in geoserver it is working fine.**
**When i am using above code to zoom to result i am gettin Error like**

```
   **<ServiceException>
      java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
java.io.IOExceptionInvalid value for parameter gid
</ServiceException>**
```

Can anyone help what is error in it.

Comment: I am Doing same but i am getting error like "java.lang.runtimeException"

Comment: I solved this issue by ading regular expression in geoserver  ^[\d,]+$